# CATiledLayer above normal CALayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, calayer

I am trying to add two sublayers on a layer. One layer should act as a (fast rendering) background while the other (the CATiledLayer) should display other content. However, the CATiledLayer won't appear at front. The normal CALayer always hides the CATiledLayer. When I remove the line

```
[self.layer addSublayer:lowRes];
```

the CATiledLayer is visible. But the background is not off course.

Here is the relevant code part

```
tiledLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
//tiledLayer.delegate = self;
tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(800.0, 800.0);
tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 4;
tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 4;
tiledLayer.frame = pageRect;
tiledLayer.zPosition = 2;
[tiledLayer setNeedsLayout];
[tiledLayer retain];

CALayer * lowRes = [CALayer layer];
lowRes.frame = tiledLayer.frame;
lowRes.zPosition = 1;
lowRes.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"krant.jpg"].CGImage;
[self.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];    
[self.layer addSublayer:lowRes];
```

How can i make the CATiledLayer visible above the CALayer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

already tried to invert the addSubLayer calls?

```
[self.layer addSublayer:lowRes];

[self.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];
```

Comment: In my implementation, layers are added in order meronix wrote.

Comment: Yes. I can be 100% sure but I think I had the same problem and that's why I added layers in that order.